# Create blank disk image for file storage

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk-image

Similar to the way Mac OS X users can create and mount blank .dmg files, add and remove files as much as they wish, and move that image wherever they want... as if it were a virtual USB drive.

Is there an equivalent for Ubuntu? I know that the "Disk Image Mounter" allows us to mount and edit existing .img files, but is there an equally easy way to create/format empty .img files? Every solution I have found so far implements copying/cloning an already existing drive, but I don't want that.

EDIT: I created a scripted GUI application based on the answer accepted below. It's just a dialog based on YAD and .sh files, it's meant to make the dd command/mount/format process easier to handle for not-so-command-line-savvy people.

[Here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzXApKOYuvy8NWMzWHNST3lOUm8/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.

This is a step-by-step guide to create a custom image starting from scratch;

I'll assume the following:

- The image size should be 100 MiB
- The image partition table should be MBR
- The image should contain a single FAT32 primary partition

---

### Creating the blank image

Create the blank image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=image.img iflag=fullblock bs=1M count=100 && sync
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % dd if=/dev/zero of=image.img iflag=fullblock bs=1M count=100 && sync
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 0.0415825 s, 2.5 GB/s
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % tree
.
└── image.img

0 directories, 1 file
```

### Mounting the blank image

List the already busy loopback devices:

```
losetup
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % losetup                   
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  1 /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs
```

Mount the image on the first available loopback device:

```
sudo losetup loop1 image.img
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % sudo losetup loop1 image.img
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  1 /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs
/dev/loop1         0      0         0  0 /home/ubuntu/tmp/image.img
```

### Partitioning / formatting the blank image

Run `gparted` passing the loopback device as an argument:

```
sudo -H gparted /dev/loop1
```

[image: screenshot1]

Click on "Device" -> "Create Partition Table...":

[image: screenshot2]

Click "Apply":

[image: screenshot3]

Click on "Partition" -> "New":

[image: screenshot4]

Select "fat32" from the drop-down menu:

[image: screenshot5]

Click "Add":

[image: screenshot6]

Click the green tick:

[image: screenshot7]

Click "Apply":

[image: screenshot8]

Click "Close":

[image: screenshot9]

And close Gparted.

### Unmounting the image

Finally, unmount the image from the loopback device:

```
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % sudo losetup -d /dev/loop1
ubuntu@ubuntu ~/tmp % losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  1 /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs
```

---

You can use the created image for whatever purpose you want; for example, you can use it as a virtual USB drive:

```
sudo losetup loop1 image.img
```

Opening Files:

[image: screenshot10]

[image: screenshot11]

Comment: @johnkieran You're welcome :)

Comment: Very detailed. Bookmarked :) and+1 of course

Comment: Thanks @A.B. :) gonna check the moderator tools right now!

Comment: Excellent, very helpful  and works for read/write when mounted. Mounting using the Linux UI kept saying read only.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install hfsutils package:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsutils
```

Now, create an image file, the size is fixed:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/file.img bs=1M count=130
```

Then, format the image file:

```
sudo hformat -l File /root/file.img
```

After that, mount the image:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/file
sudo mount -t hfs -o loop /root/file.img /mnt/file
```

Copy your files into your new mounted volume and when you finish unmount it:

```
sudo umount /mnt/file
```

I referred to this [link](https://serverhorror.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/create-dmg-images-for-os-x-on-linux/) to find the solution.
Ps: I tested it successfully in my Ubuntu MATE 14.04.3

Comment: there is a problem with Ubuntu Mate. Please, look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670369/what-is-the-correct-way-to-mount-an-img-in-fstab